# ant and greater than

Tags: javascript, ant, ant-contrib

I was trying to follow this stackoverflow link:

initially , I started looking for a way to do greaterthan in ant and I found few ways which all caused problems to me.

1. I found a way, to do it by using javascript task:
   [How can I compare two properties with numeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639902/apache-ant-comparing-properties-variables)

but I got the following error message:
Unable to load a script engine manager (org.apache.bsf.BSFManager or javax.script.ScriptEngineManager)

I was trying to add a bsf jar and was unsuccessful to do so.
can you please give me an example..?

2. I was trying to use the ant-contrib additional properties for `<bool>` element which are suggested in the following link:
   http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html

and I was unsuccessful to do so. Can you please give me an example..?

Answer (score 2):

The following ANT demo works for me without the need to install additional libraries:

```
<project name="hello" default="demo">
    <target name="demo">
        <script language="javascript">
            var version = parseInt(project.getProperty('version'));
            project.setProperty('isGreater', version > 1);
        </script>

        <echo message="${isGreater}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

What version of ANT and Java are you using?
In my case:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first error message you got:

```
Unable to load a script engine manager (org.apache.bsf.BSFManager or javax.script.ScriptEngineManager)
```

This is telling you that you are missing a Jar file. Look at the [`<script>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task:

> Note: This task depends on external libraries not included in the Apache Ant distribution. See [Library Dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) for more information.

The Library Dependency link will take you to a table. Search for the words *script task*. There are up to 10 optional jars needed for the script task to work. The one you need is the [bsf.jar](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/).

To use the *Ant Contrib* tasks, you need the Ant Contrib Jarfile, and to link to the tasks with a `<taskdef>` task. Here's how to do it:

- Download the latest version of [ant-contrib.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.tar.gz/download).
- Make a directory in your project called `antlib/ant-contrib` and put the ant-contrib.jar in that directory.

In your `build.xml` you want to do the following near the top. This can be done outside of any task:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
       <fileset dir="${basedir}/antlib/ant-contrib"/>
   </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Now, you should be able to use [ant-contrib task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) including the [`<bool>`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html) condition.

Comment: thanks a lot. I do get this error. I was trying to add the jar as you suggested, but how do I import/include a jar to be used in build.xml?

I was trying to follow the way I import/include ant-conrtib , and tried:

  <taskdef resource="org/apache/bsf/Languages.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${home.dir}/library/bsf.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

but still I got the same error...

can you please advise me what to do?

Comment: The problem is that the `<scripts>` task is already defined in Ant, so `taskdef` won't work. Instead, put the bsf.jar into your ANT_HOME/lib directory. This is in Ant's built in Classpath. Otherwise, you'll need to pass the `-lib` parameter in Ant, or create a file called `antrc_pre.bat` in your HOME/HOMEPATH/USERPROFILE directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<scriptdef name="val1_mayorque_val2" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="val1" />
    <attribute name="val2" />
    <attribute name="resultado" />
    <![CDATA[
        if(attributes.get("val1") > attributes.get("val2"))
            project.setProperty(attributes.get("resultado"), "si");
        else
            project.setProperty(attributes.get("resultado"), "no");
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

Call it with this:

```
<val1_mayorigualque_val2 val1="5" val2="3" resultado="result"/>
```

val1 = value 1
val2 = value 2

After use that, you must to test ${result}. Id it has "si" value, then val1 is greater than val2.